# Como hacer que una variable sea igual al contenido de un archivo en Js?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Tengo una variable que es igual a un link, cuando entro a ese link se descarga inmediatamente un archivo csv. Mi duda es como tengo que hacer si yo a ese archivo ya lo tengo en mi PC y quiero que la variable sea igual a la direccion del archivo local.

Por ejemplo:

```html
<script>
   var arbitraryCsvFile = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/6337/hondiff.csv";
</script>
```

Yo necesito que sea arbitraryCsvFile = (archivo csv guardado en mi pc)

Comment: en lugar del protocolo `https://`  usa el `file:///` con la ruta. Truco: Abre el navegador en una página vacia y arrastra ese archivo tal cual desde tu explorador de archivos, y te aparecerá el protocolo y la ruta correctas en el campo de la URL.  Si no te deja cambiale la extensión a .html temporalmente para que te lo permita y puedas cazar esa url

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir, realmente? Tener el path de un archivo local no te es muy útil, no puedes leerlo desde tu página.

Comment: cuando se trata de desarrollo web nada es "local", si tienes este archivo de forma local tienes que hacerle un httprequest, si estas usando javascript puro se hace con XMLHttpRequest, con jQuery se hace con ajax, etc.